# Tub drain renovation

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub, renovation

So I'm renovating an old, rusty tub to avoid replacing it.  The drain and overflow valve were rusty and holes were made to remove them. So far,  I've used Bondo to fill in gaps, which is working great.  When sanding the tub I've noticed areas are thicker than others around the drain.   Do I need to continue sanding to thin it out so it drains properly or is that even an issue?
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a cast iron tub, or the thin pressed-steel type?

Comment: It's pressed steel I believe.  It's pretty thin and the torn edges broke off easy enough.  I do have photos if that helps.